# Get value from referenced project's controller into main project controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, .net-assembly

I have many ASP.NET MVC applications that have the same code for headers so I created a separate ASP.NET MVC shared project for the header. I load data from a stored procedure into a model to populate the menus in the header, installed RazorGenerator to compile the views and the reference the dll in my individual applications. It works great.

There is some data from the stored procedure which gets some values for the header menus that I would like to have in my consuming applications. Is it possible to get these values somehow from my consuming ASP.NET MVC projects? It seems impossible. It would be nice if I could just get it from the referenced DLL somehow so I don't have to make a second, redundant call. I've tried the following and nothing works:

- In the shared project settings Session or Tempdata variables. These do not come over into the consuming projects. Values are null
- I can't instantiate a new class like

  ```
  ReferencedNamespace.modelrow bla = new ReferencedNamespace.modelrow();
  ```

  Technically this is the only way I've been able to get values back, but this essentially makes two calls to the DB through the referenced project's model so it defeats the purpose.
- In the referenced projects's class I tried making a property:

  ```
  public string myvalue
  {
      get
      {
          return valuetoget;
      }
  }
  ```

  and in the controller that populates the model initially I add

  ```
  valuetoget = whatever comes back from the stored procedure here
  ```

But there's no way to refer to referenceNamespace.Controllers.Controllername.valuetopass. Again I can instantiate it from the consuming project and this again calls it twice. So it's no use.

Is there anyway I can hand off this data from the referenced DLL's controller to consuming applications? Like I said, I really don't want to have to break my original header stored procedure into two stored procedures or make redundant calls.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using sessions. Initially I set the Session values in the controller action method but the problem is when I was checking the session data in my main projects' controller actions, the values were null, causing errors when checking user profile info inside my views. So I just assumed that class libraries in referenced libraries could read the consuming application's session variables, but couldn't set them.

I was wrong. you *can*.

Basically, when I add my header view (which comes from the referenced library) in the Razor code, the code for that header view in the referenced project doesn't execute until AFTER all the consuming project action code is called for the current view and returned...  so essentially I'm trying to get session fields before they exist. That's why they were null.

You would THINK that the SECOND time I ran the page (doing a refresh) THEN the session fields would be there because the referenced action method would have loaded them, but they still were null. I still don't know why and I'd like to figure it out... BUT I basically just ended up doing this successfully:

I set my consuming project's controllers to inherit from custom class. Then inside the overriden OnActionExecuting() method of this custom class... I check to see if my Session fields are null. If they are, then this is (probably) the first time we're running this so I THEN create a new instance of my referenced controller.  I take this instance and call the action method for the header. This will cause an "initial load" of session data before any controllers in any project (referenced or consuming) attempt to fire ANY action code. This will make sure that when any controller tries to reference these session fields, they will be there.

Technically, this causes my sproc to redundantly run twice when the header is loaded but ONLY on the first time the page is loaded or if something clears the session which is fine by me.

I've read that Sessions are a bad way to send data back and forth between classes BUT in this case, this is user profile information that I wanted to load into Session variables anyways so in my case it works out. If this was any other type of data, I'd have a problem.